# Count large file downloads from apache logs in mysql

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, logging

I want to count file downloads for about 10 different files that a client has asked for. We've generated a separate log format for the apache logs that can be loaded into a MySQL database.

For such a specific query I was hoping to be able to write a SQL statement to count the downloads rather than installing an over-bloated log analyser.

This is the log format used for the MySQL logs:

```
LogFormat "\"%a\",%{%Y%m%d%H%M%S}t,%>s,\"%b\",\"%{Content-Type}o\", \"%U\",\"%{Referer}i\",\"%{User-Agent}i\"" mysql
```

This produces this kind of csv file:

```
"156.107.33.66",20121017113516,200,"10094440","application/x-msdos-program",          "/flexnet/FLEXnetWinSetup.exe","http://www.example.com/downloads/flexnet","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4"
```

But the larger 100MB+ files are split into chunks so its not a simple count of the logs.

Has anyone tried something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by split into chuncks you means that clients are donwloading the files with multiple 206 HTTP responses then you should try to log the content of header Content-Range included into the reply :

```
LogFormat "\"%a\",%{%Y%m%d%H%M%S}t,%>s,\"%b\",\"%{Content-Range}o\",\"%{Content-Type}o\", \"%U\",\"%{Referer}i\",\"%{User-Agent}i\"" mysql
```

This should produces something like this (not tested)

```
"156.107.33.66",20121017113516,200,"10094440","bytes 0-999/3980","application/x-msdos-program",          "/flexnet/FLEXnetWinSetup.exe","http://www.example.com/downloads/flexnet","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4"
```